# Is it possible to use parameterised test case data with Xcode's XCTest Framework?

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, xctest

Something similar to the `TestCaseAttribute` that [NUnit has](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCase&r=2.5), along the lines of:

```
[TestCase(12,3,4)]
[TestCase(12,2,6)]
[TestCase(12,4,3)]
public void DivideTest(int n, int d, int q)
{
  Assert.AreEqual( q, n / d );
}
```

Is it possible to provide parameterised test case data like this, in Xcode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not look like XCTest has this built in, but there is project on [GitHub](https://github.com/konoma/xctest-parametrized-tests) aims to add this functionaltiy.

From their ReadMe:

> KNMParametrizedTest adds support for parametrized test cases using the XCTest framework. Here is an example:

`KNMParametersFor(testExample, @[ @"Hello", @"World" ])
- (void)testExample:(NSString *)word
{
    NSString *result = [myUppercaser uppercaseString:word];
    XCTAssertEqualObjects(result, [word uppercaseString],
                          @"Uppercaser failed for word %@", word);
}`

It looks like the easiest way to install this is through CocoaPods.

Comment: Thanks for that GitHub find.

Comment: The link appears to be broken :(

Answer (score 0):

Although XCTest doesn't offer a proper means of writing parameterized tests, I found a nice, simple workaround in [page 46](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=z-fIDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA46) of Godfrey Nolan's book [Agile Swift](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=z-fIDQAAQBAJ) which is to define an array of tuples containing the input and output values, and then to iterate through each item in the array, as follows:

```
func test_multiple() {
    let cases = [(4,3,12),(2,4,8)]
    cases.forEach {
         XCTAssertEqual(myCalculator.multiply($0, $1), $2)
    }
}
```

The only caveat with this approach that I can see is that you'll only get one entry in the test navigator / test report rather than one for each test case. But the time you'll save from not having to write the same test again and again (with only a slight variation in each test) is well worth it in my opinion.

If you want a nice message in the case of a failed test, you can easily get this by adding one more element to the tuple which represents the message to pass into the `XCTAssertEqual` call, as follows:

```
func test_multiple() {
    let cases = [(4,3,12,"4 times 3"),(2,4,8,"2 times 4")]
    cases.forEach {
         XCTAssertEqual(myCalculator.multiply($0, $1), $2, $3)
    }
}
```